# Select query for group amounts per month and year (MySql)

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I have a table name "transactionshistory" with columns

[image]

and I would like to create a select query where a SUM the amounts per month and year

for example

```
Total_Amount | MONTH | YEAR
   100       |  01   | 2018
   110       |  02   | 2018
```

Comment: Have you even tried anything???

Comment: @Eric thanks for your reply.Very helpful

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a free coding service website.  Show what you did.  If you're stuck, post your code.  We'll try to help you.  Don't just post your question, asking for answer without even trying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(amount) Total_Amount, 
       MONTH(transactiondate) `MONTH`, 
       YEAR(transactiondate) `YEAR`
FROM transactionshistory
GROUP BY MONTH(transactiondate), YEAR(transactiondate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your prompt reply Akina.

```
MONTH | INCOME | EXPENSES | DIFFERENCE
```

where INCOME represents the sum for all positive values
and  EXPENSES represents the sum for all negative values
per month

I have tried the bellow

```
SELECT  MONTH(transactiondate) `MONTH`, 
   YEAR(transactiondate) `YEAR`,
    SUM(CASE when amount <0 then amount END) EXPENSES ,
   SUM(CASE when amount >=0 then amount END) INCOME ,
   SUM(amount) Total_Amount 
FROM transactionshistory
GROUP BY MONTH(transactiondate), YEAR(transactiondate) order by MONTH desc
```

Comment: Please edit your original question and put this in there. Then, if you want Akina's attention, put a comment with @Akina in the text and he will be notified. He may or may not have seen this! There are a few articles on how to ask questions here on my profile - you might want to take a look? These sites are a great resource and you will get all the more from them if you follow the guidelines. Also, it would be a good idea to indicate what the problem is with the result of the SQL above - it looks OK to me. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)